# Change Python version from 3.5.3 to 3.5.2

Tags: python, python3

I need to downgrade my `python3.5` from `3.5.3` to `3.5.2` because of some `asyncio` features. I installed `python3.5` using next commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

But there was no options like selecting needed version. Is it possible to downgrade to `3.5.2`?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should make sure is whether `3.5.2` version is available in your repository. You can check that by running `apt-cache policy python3.5`. Check all the available candidate versions.

If `3.5.2` is available then install it using `apt-get install python3.5=3.5.2`

If not then add the respective ppa which hosts the `3.5.2` version and `apt-get update` and install it using the above command.

**WARNING**: Downgrading the package from external repositories might break the system. It's always recommended to use the distribution provided repository which are well tested before releasing.Use with caution!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution. But also it will delete all modules you have.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.5.2.tgz
cd Python-3.5.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```